# Can I make indexOf compare objects in a different way?

Tags: java, equals, equality, indexof

I want to use `indexOf` but the objects in the `List` will not be equal objects but they would have value equality (ie. they're equivalent but not equal).

I want to make `indexOf` compare in a different way than the `Object.equals` method. I was thinking overridding the equals method to use my isEquivalent method instead but am unsure how to do this, if it is even possible.

I've tried many variations of this but keep getting errors:

```
List<CustomType> items{
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
    = //stuff to populate it
```

I've also seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/175988/4714970) where they talk about EqualityComparer's is there something like that in java?

Or is there some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe you are getting errors because `equals` returns `boolean` not `void`?

Comment: @cricket_007 haha oops, fixed that now. and no that wasn't the cause

Comment: Maybe add your `isEquivalent` method. Also, from what you have here you are trying to override `equals` on the `List` interface, not the `CustomType` object.

Comment: @cricket_007 the problem isn't with my isEquivalent method because it's the same sort of errors if I just return false. What do you mean by that second part? Aren't I trying to override the equals on the list so that when items.indexOf is called which uses equals, it will use the equals that i've posted instead right?

Comment: No, the way your wrote it, you are defining equals for the List. You need, for example, (with poor formatting) `class CustomType { @Override boolean equals(Object o) { } }` because `indexOf` uses `equals` on the objects it contains.

Comment: @cricket_007 oh I think I get it, so if I have `a.indexOf(b);` do I need to override the equals of `a` or of `b`?

Comment: equals of `b`, or you could see the answer I provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my crack at it. I used `ArrayList` because List is an interface and you would have needed to override all the methods.

```
List<CustomType> customList = new ArrayList<CustomType>() {
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        if (o instanceof CustomType) {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++) {
                CustomType c = (CustomType) o;
                if (c.isEquivalent(this.get(i))) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
// use indexOf like normal, but beware of side-effects as mentioned in the comments
```

---

#### Alternatively

What I was trying to say in the comments earlier is that if you override `List.equals`, that implies you are comparing the `List` object with another object, not the objects within the list. To do what you are asking, you need to do it like this.

```
class CustomType {

    public boolean isEquivalent(CustomType ct) {
        return true; // TODO: Implement this
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // TODO: Implement this
        if (obj instanceof CustomType) {
            return this.isEquivalent((CustomType) obj); 
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode(); // TODO: Implement this
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<CustomType> lst = new ArrayList<CustomType>();
    // use indexOf like normal
}
```

Comment: The trouble with this sort of thing is there are many consequences, and you have to study the source code of `ArrayList` to know what they are. For example, it changes the behaviour of `contains` too, because `ArrayList` currently implements `contains` as just `return indexOf(o) >= 0;`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington - True. It also makes the list completely dependent upon the CustomType class.

Comment: I don't understand why I have to override indexOf and not equals here??

Comment: @Aequitas - because that was your question :) "can I make indexOf compare Objects in a different way"

Comment: I thought it'd have been simpler to just override equals as it'd be only one line instead of indexof no? Also how do I do this when I'm making it equal some data or do i have to create a new List first and then add to it?

Comment: okay thanks, I think I get it. That won't work for me as I need the equals to be the default one in other cases

Comment: Alright, well then I think @PaulBoddington's solution would be what you want (though a little verbose) - just write your own `indexOf` method that takes the list as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

The lack of something like `EqualityComparer` is, in my view, one of the worst things about standard java. It means that if you want to use objects in a collection such as an `ArrayList` or `HashSet`, you are stuck with just one notion of equality for methods such as `indexOf` and `contains`. This is very, very annoying. It's in complete contrast to `TreeSet`, which is much more flexible and allows you to use a `Comparator` to specify the order you want for the `Set`.

I would advise against overriding `indexOf` to mean something different to what people expect. It would be likely to cause bugs and confusion. Also, it is likely that you would want to be able to use `indexOf` with the usual meaning at some point.

Instead you could write your own `EqualityComparer` interface

```
public interface EqualityComparer<E> {

    boolean areEqual(E e1, E e2);

    int hash(E e);  // Not needed for indexOf, but very useful in general
}
```

Then you could write a static method `indexOf` like this:

```
public static <E> int indexOf(List<? extends E> list, E item, EqualityComparer<? super E> comparer) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        if (comparer.areEqual(list.get(i), item))
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override equals() and hashcode() in your custom object. If two objects are equal, their hashcodes should also be equal.