# Having trouble with accessing an object name variable to search for the objects index in an Arraylist

Tags: java

Currently, I have a code which looks something like this:

`cities.get(cities.indexOf(city)).edges.add(new GraphEdge(cities.indexOf(city), index, Integer.parseInt(miles)));`

where `city` is a variable of the name of a city and I'm trying to access the index of the object who's variable `name.equals(city) = true;`

I realized that the statement: `cities.get(cities.indexOf(city))` is looking for the memory block which equals the city value (I believe?), which obviously isn't going to give me what I'm looking for.

How can I find the index of an object who has a variable "name" which is equal to the variable "city"?

Comment: As I see it you need a custom `equals` or `comparator` for the `indexOf` method to achieve this. Have a look at this discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989483/can-i-make-indexof-compare-objects-in-a-different-way

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams.

```
cities.stream().filter(c -> c.getName().equals(city)).findFirst().ifPresent(c -> {
  //do something with the city
});
```