# indexOf() returns -1

Tags: java, android, indexof

I'm trying to replace an item in my recycler view and for that I need to get the index of an object(recipe) inside a list in SQLite database and it returns -1.Any idea??.

```
private void editRecipe(Intent data) {


        if (data.hasExtra(Recipe.RECIPE_KEY) && data.hasExtra(Recipe.RECIPE_NAME)&& data.hasExtra(Recipe.RECIPE_DESCRIPTION)&& data.hasExtra(Recipe.RECIPE_DIFFICULTY))
        {
            Recipe recipe = (Recipe) data.getSerializableExtra(Recipe.RECIPE_KEY);
            Long id = data.getExtras().getLong(Recipe.RECIPE_ID);
            String name = (String) data.getExtras().get(Recipe.RECIPE_NAME);
            String description = (String) data.getExtras().get(Recipe.RECIPE_DESCRIPTION);
            int difficulty = (int) data.getExtras().get(Recipe.RECIPE_DIFFICULTY);



            //find the recipe in the list

                    //Boolean result= recipeDataService.update(recipe);
                    int position = adapter.getRecipes().indexOf(recipe);
                    if(position >= 0){
                        //recipe was found
                        recipe = recipeDataService.getRecipe(id);
                        Boolean result= recipeDataService.update(recipe);

                        adapter.replaceItem(position, recipe);

                }
            }

        }        }

´´´
```

Comment: simply because index of compares objects to each other and this newly recipe you're creating doesn't match the same one that was saved before (not same in reference), so to overcome this I think (but not sure) you should override equals function in your recipe class to only compare the data you hold inside the class not the object itself

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make indexOf compare objects in a different way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989483/can-i-make-indexof-compare-objects-in-a-different-way)